# MAC OSX Mavericks, using bash to see "Get Info" attributes

Tags: macos, mac, bash, osx-mavericks

I want to use my bash shell to see the attributes that are shown when you right click on an Application and click `Get Info`. The specific attributes that I want to know whether or not they are checked is `Open in Low Resolution`, `Prevent App Nap`, and `Locked`.

I looked in the `Info.plist` file but only generic information about the file was contained here, not which attributes were checked.

Is this information contained in the Applications binary? Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

The locked setting is stored as a Finder flag:

```
find /Applications/Application.app -maxdepth 1 -flags +uchg|grep -q .&&echo locked
GetFileInfo /Applications/Application.app|grep -q '^attributes:.*L'&&echo locked
```

The app nap disabled settings are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`:

```
$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print LSAppNapIsDisabled:com.haystacksoftware.Arq:0' ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist
bookH0P
       ApplicationsArq.a�p
�C8A�@�H���A�1M�$5DF7A03E-A7FB-3E80-B61D-F10CD8BF7B5D/ /Applications/Arq.app�����(Xx 0H@h  � � � �  �0 �$�0
```

`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to info for (POSIX file "/Applications/Application.app")'` does not include either of those settings.